# Android Studio - Using XML id in the java code

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I have this line of code

```
adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.cars10, R.layout.teste);
```

where cars10 is an string array, but what happens is that I have 10 string arrays: cars1,cars2,cars3...and so on...

I'd like to know if I can do it in an easy way, for example

```
for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)adapter[i] = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.cars+"i", R.layout.teste);``
```

ps: I know it does not work, it's so you guys can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try something like that:

```
<resources>
    <string-array name="carA">
        <item>1</item>
        <item>2</item>
    </string-array>

    <string-array name="carB">
        <item>3</item>
        <item>4</item>
    </string-array>

    <array name="myArrays">
        <item>@array/carA</item>
        <item>@array/carB</item>
    </array>
</resources>

 final TypedArray arr = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.myArrays);
 final int arrayId= arr.getResourceId(0, 0);
```

you then can use the arrayId

Comment: why (0,0)?
why is there two indexes if it's not a matrix?

Comment: the second one is a default value if key does not exist